# How to include "#" in properties file. '\#' escape doesn't work

Tags: java, c#, properties

I need to include value with # in properties file but # is used to comment line in properties file. How to I do it.

I want to define mapping something as follow

`someField[#]=someValue`

But anything after `#` get commented. 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on Java 8 works fine without any escape character

Example below

**properties**

```
name# = #John#
```

**Java code**

```
System.out.println( p.getProperty("name#"));
```

**Prints:**    #John#

Edit:

If the key contains the first character as # in that case you need to escape it with '\' in properties file

e.g.

```
\#country# = #India#
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the `#` with `\`, like

```
someField\#=1
```

which will get you `{someField#=1}`

Comment: @PrakashSharma I tested it. `key\#=1` (in a properties file), read it with `Properties.load(InputStream)` and got `{key#=1}`.

Answer (score 0):

write it like this :

```
key\#1=value\#1
```

other special characters like '=', ':' work the same.

Code in Java:

1. write properties:

   ```
   Properties p =  new Properties();
   p.load(PropertiesTest.class.getResourceAsStream("prop.properties"));
   p.setProperty("key#=dsafw", "value $#@^$%@**^");
   p.setProperty("key#1", "value#1");
   p.store(new FileOutputStream(new File("../TEMP/prop.properties")), "write special property kvs");
   ```
2. read properties:

   ```
   p.load(new FileInputStream(new File("../TEMP/prop.properties")));
   Enumeration<Object> keys = p.keys();
   while(keys.hasMoreElements()){
     String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
     System.out.println("key --> " + key + ", value --> " + p.getProperty(key));
   }
   ```

Comment: Hash is used to comment in properties files.. It is not working