# Spring environment variable not correctly read into property

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

This question is not about escaping characters such as = or " in the property.  The questions are:

1. How do I get the expected values, e.g. for the password I want `DE#F` and not `DE`
2. More academically; why is this happening?

(I assume) Spring is not reading in the environment variables correctly that contains an # in the string - on Linux. E.g.:

The yml file:

```
# Spring Boot configuration in yml file
application:
    username: Clark Kent
    password: abc
```

The overriding environmental variable in `/etc/environment`

```
APPLICATION_USERNAME="Ronald Raygan" #Maybe use a stronger password?
APPLICATION_PASSWORD="DE#F"
```

In the application, the following values are used:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {    
    private String username;
    private String password;
    // rest of the class
}
```

In another class:

```
System.out.println(applicationProperties.getUsername());
System.out.println(applicationProperties.getPassword());
```

This will print out:

```
Ronald Raygan"
DE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape the equals sign in properties files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406975/how-to-escape-the-equals-sign-in-properties-files)

Comment: what exactly is the question?

Comment: If you want quotes, probably you have to escape the character. The same thing for cardinal, because it's the character for comments.

Comment: @pvpkiran Nope, I've tried escaping the text, I only end up with the \ in the property. e.g. `password="DE\#F"` gives me `DE\` (The \ is escaped in the String)

Comment: @Stultuske The question is: how to get the expected values, e.g `DE#F` and not `DE`

Comment: @voliveira89 nope don't want the quotes, I've also tried escaping the # but it doesn't work

Comment: @TungstenX  # indicates comments in your properties files. meaning, you'll have to escape those. Not sure how, though

Comment: @Stultuske I've even tried to double escape the # e.g. `\\#`

Comment: that's how you escape in Java, but you're working in a propeties file. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605080/how-to-include-in-properties-file-escape-doesnt-work

Comment: Have you tried unicode escapes (eg `\u0023`)?